# Moving bed Y-axis belt keeps skipping after replacement

Tags: bed-leveling, y-axis, anycubic-i3-mega, anycubic-chiron, anycubic-ultrabase

I replaced my belt that had snapped and tightened it with the tension adjuster. Now, either the tension is too tight to allow the Y-axis belt motors to move the bed, or otherwise, the bed skips at some point during the print at least once, offsetting the entire print and ruining it.

Perhaps I could increase the power to the motor, but how would I do that, and also is that smart judging by the factory settings power limit? I don't want to overpower the motor, the belt is pretty much identical to the one before it so I would imagine it should be the same performance.

- Klipper + FluiddPI
- Raspberry Pi 3+
- Anycubic Mega X

[Here is a link](https://share.icloud.com/photos/057p0SJQC3TSsunzAtOuIjDEw) to some videos of the belt being moved manually. I can see it skipping on the belt here at various tensions. does this show anything particularly telling? I am almost certain the two belts are the same, but maybe I'm wrong..

Belt tight (too tight to allow the Y-axis belt motors to move the bed):
[image]

Belt loose (the bed skips at some point during the print):
[image]

Comment: If the old belt was so tight it snapped, I would be worried the motor bearings are completely shot and the motor shaft binding, or that the mounting brackets are bent. A belt has to be **extremely** overtightened before it will snap, so much that it would do other damage.

Comment: when i tighten too much it it doesnt move, when i loosen it it still skips but less often, until  i loosen to a point where its just far too loose to do anything.
I mightve broken it when trying to move te bed and adding too much pressure while the motors were engaged, im not sure because i noticed it broke so after the fact. .
How would I determine any of the potentialities you listed above?

Comment: Remove the belt and rotate the shaft by hand, not powering the machine, preferably dislodge the cable, see if it rotates normally (compare with another stepper). A replacement stepper (you need type A of the Anycubic replacement steppers) costs about 15 Euro, I'd order a spare and see what that does, not expensive and always handy.

Comment: just did that, that's what in the video actually, i was moving by hand. didn't see any abnormalities but it did look like some weird disturbance was happening in the cord, not sure if its the stepper motor or belt design. The belt as far as I can tell is identical to the original...